# Getting error while importing flanker mime

Tags: regex, python-3.x, email

Getting the following error while importing flanker mime

```
    RE_RE = re.compile("((RE|FW|FWD|HA)([[]\d])*:\s*)*", re.I)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/regex.py", line 345, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags, kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/regex.py", line 507, in _compile
    caught_exception.pos)
_regex_core.error: unterminated character set at position 30
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of background about what your regex should match or should not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the regex module that was imported by the flanker library.
I resolved the issue by changing import regex -> import re

Answer (score 0):

You error comes from this part of your regex:

```
[[]\d]
```

Can you escape the brackets properly and change it into

```
[\[\]\d]
```

or into

```
\[[\]\d]
```

or even into

```
\[\[\]\d\]
```

depending on what you want to capture?

The way it is right now `[[]\d]` causes ambiguity (brackets used as simple character or as keyword to define character class) to your regex processor.